# MySQL JSON - using IN statement | json_contains

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I'm trying to select all columns where the `roles` property in the `json` column contains ANY of the values.

Statements I've tried:

`SELECT * FROM components WHERE json->'$.roles' IN(1)`

- this doesn't even work but it should in my opinion...

`SELECT * FROM components WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(components, '1', '$.roles')`

- this does work however is strict, so when I use `1` it pulls both like it should because they both contain 1, however if I insert `1,2` or `JSON_ARRAY(1,2)` it will only pull the later row because it isn't checking per array element...

I have the following table `components` **structure** and **data**:

```
+====+========================================================================================================================================================================================================+==+
| id |                                                                                                  json                                                                                                  |  |
+====+========================================================================================================================================================================================================+==+
|  1 | {"area": 1, "roles": [1], "elements": [{"home": {"content": "Home", "attributes": {"class": "my_class_1"}}}, {"dashboard": {"content": "Dashboard", "attributes": {"class": "my_class_1"}}}]}          |  |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|  2 | {"area": 1, "roles": [1, 2, 5], "elements": [{"home": {"content": "Testing", "attributes": {"class": "my_class_1"}}}, {"dashboard": {"content": "Dashboard", "attributes": {"class": "my_class_1"}}}]} |  |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

**Question:** How can I modify either of these statements to allow them to query the rows based on the values in the `roles` property?

Comment: `json->'$.roles'` is an array, `1` is a single number. An array is not equal to a number.

Comment: @Barmar agreed, even if I use `[1,2]` or `JSON_ARRAY(1,2)` in the `JSON_CONTAINS()` it will error because it doesn't like the `value` parameter an array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression

```
value in (x, y, z, ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
value = x OR value = y OR value = z OR ...
```

This doesn't work for an array like `json->'$.roles'` because an array is not equal to its elements, you need to call `JSON_CONTAINS()` to test that.

For what you want, you need to call `JSON_CONTAINS()` for each value you want to test.

```
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(components, '1', '$.roles') OR JSON_CONTAINS(components, '2', '$.roles')
```

Comment: Yeah I've seen that... it just looks "hackish" doesn't it? but yeah it may be only way  possible to achieve it. Is this possible to make dynamic though?

Comment: Came up with a better answer.

Comment: Yeah I tried exactly that! only thing is it's strict so like `JSON_ARRAY(1,2)` won't return rows with roles that contain `1` only if it's in that exact order.

Comment: Oh right, it wants to match them all, not any. I think it will have to go back to the `OR` version.

Comment: ```JSON_OVERLAPS(..)``` based solution should be the preferred answer. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62795451/2469308

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya My answer is 6 years old, when JSON_OVERLAPS didn't exist.

Comment: my comment is for future readers, so that they can rather use the direct function available in MySQL now!

Answer (score 12):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-overlaps

`JSON_OVERLAPS(json_doc1, json_doc2)`

Compares two JSON documents. Returns true (1) if the two document have any key-value pairs or array elements in common. If both arguments are scalars, the function performs a simple equality test.

This function serves as counterpart to `JSON_CONTAINS()`, which requires all elements of the array searched for to be present in the array searched in. Thus, `JSON_CONTAINS()` performs an AND operation on search keys, while `JSON_OVERLAPS()` performs an OR operation.

Queries on JSON columns of InnoDB tables using `JSON_OVERLAPS()` in the WHERE clause can be optimized using multi-valued indexes. Multi-Valued Indexes, provides detailed information and examples.

When comparing two arrays, `JSON_OVERLAPS()` returns true if they share one or more array elements in common, and false if they do not.

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,5,7]");
+---------------------------------------+
| JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,5,7]") |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,6,7]");
+---------------------------------------+
| JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,6,7]") |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     1 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,6,8]");
+---------------------------------------+
| JSON_OVERLAPS("[1,3,5,7]", "[2,6,8]") |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     0 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

try one of these it should work

```
SELECT * FROM components WHERE JSON_CONTAINS([1],  roles, '$');

SELECT * FROM components WHERE JSON_CONTAINS([1],  CAST(roles as JSON), '$');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried because i got a similar issue, and the following works for me:

```
field->'$.sub' REGEXP '^(1|3|5)$'
```

Yes, it seems that it is possible to use regular expressions here...

Note that if you try to query a string field in the json you should considder that strings are surrounded by a `"`, so you have to query something like this:

```
customer->'$.mail' REGEXP '^\"(info|contact)@.*\.com\"$'
```

Hope it helps, but i dont know how that impacts in performance...