# Check json_contains on json of json in mysql table

Tags: mysql, json

I have json data in my table which contains again json value like below sample data

This is laravel audits, audits table `new_values` column ( type: text ) record 
but for this particular case I am not using eloquent or query builder, it is just a raw query

`{"video_status_ids":"[6, 8, 14, 29]"}`

now I want to check if this has 8 in it.

I tried

```
select * from audits WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(new_values, '8', '$.video_status_ids')
```

and

```
JSON_CONTAINS(audits.new_values, CAST(' . $status . ' AS json), "$.video_status_ids")';
```

I tried `json_Search` to

1. `select * from audits WHERE JSON_SEARCH(new_values, 'all', '8', 'video_status_ids', '$[*]');`
2. `select * from audits WHERE JSON_SEARCH(new_values, 'all', '8', NULL, '$[video_status_ids.*]');`
3. `SELECT * FROM audits WHERE JSON_SEARCH(new_values, 'all', '8', NULL, '$.video_status_ids.*')`

Getting 0 records

and some other queries, but could not get the expected result.

by refering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294290/5321614) but I am getting 0 records on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the "array" in your JSON data is actually a string (note the double quotes around it). So to search inside it, you first need to `JSON_EXTRACT` and then `JSON_UNQUOTE` it:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(new_values, '$.video_status_ids')), '8')
FROM audits
```

You can also use the shorthand `->>` for `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT())`:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(new_values->>'$.video_status_ids', '8')
FROM audits
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd0e2dab1bf293c581a872af2d1e09f3)

Working Solution

```
SELECT * FROM audits WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(new_values->>'$.video_status_ids', '8')
```

Comment: I am getting a set of `null`s and `0`s for both of these queries.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Just realised I used `new_value` instead of `new_values` did you fix that?

Comment: Also, that is json inside json not array in side json.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu how is your data different from my demo? It works fine there...

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu regardless of it being an array or JSON (in this case they are the same) because it is quoted you need to extract it and unquote before you can search on it.

Comment: Your data seems same as mine, and I just copied and pasted in phpmyadmin console, let me check what is the difference in data.

Comment: I just checked new_values column type is text for me, is this the problem?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu it works fine as text in the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0432a9caadb8881d9acd1b0ad4d6c70c What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I have added sample data in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/0fe5b4d01cad288e948f34e440108594) Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190348/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the documentation for [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains):

> Indicates by returning 1 or 0 whether a given candidate JSON document is contained within a target JSON document

It can only check for existance of a key - not search an array.

The [`JSON_SEARCH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function however:

> Returns the path to the given string within a JSON document

This is what you need. Remember to pass your path as the last argument, since the array is not the root element.

Database.guide has a really good article about using JSON_SEARCH for your purpose (including syntax help and examples):

https://database.guide/json_search-find-the-path-to-a-string-in-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Comment: As you suggested, I tried using JSON_SEARCH, but getting error, I have edited my question,m could you please look into it once?

Comment: I was using wit wrong, so corrected it, but still getting 0 records.

Comment: This is incorrect. Try `SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('[6, 8, 14, 29]', '8')` and you will get 1 (true).